# What are the second and third "Hebrew Algebras" Mary Everest Boole refer to?

Tags: mathematics, education

In the book ["Philosophy and Fun of Algebra"](https://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/95/philosophy-and-fun-of-algebra/), Mary Everest Boole has a chapter dedicated to what she calls "the first Hebrew algebra" (Chapter 6). She later refers to the "second and third great Hebrew algebras" (Chapter 8). But what are these?

Comment: Due to the fact that "The first Hebrew algebra is called *Mosaism*, from the name of Moses the Liberator" I strongly believe that there are no historical precise reference there...

Comment: Maybe useful to note that during Boole's time there were the rediscovery of Arabic mathematics; see [The Algebra of Mohammed Ben Musa (1831)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Algebra_of_Mohammed_ben_Musa/6R-jMgEACAA) where ben Musa is the well-known Persian [Muhammad ibn Musa al-Khwarizmi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_ibn_Musa_al-Khwarizmi) and its "algebra" is the treatise on algebra [The Compendious Book on Calculation by Completion and Balancing, ca. 813–833 CE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Compendious_Book_on_Calculation_by_Completion_and_Balancing).

Comment: I'm not familiar with this text, but from browsing the chapter titles I see those called "Jacob's Ladder" and "From Bondage to Freedom" - it seems like there are biblical references sprinkled throughout and Boole is just having a little fun here.

Comment: Also Googling "the first Hebrew algebra" only finds references to this text and to the first algebra textbook published in Hebrew.